# Saving Data + String

Tags: java, string, inputstream, outputstream

I'm trying to save & load data but I'm getting frustrated & need some damn sleep. I can't seem to figure this out without getting bugs or nulls.

My code:

```
public class Offers {

public static List<Offer> offers = new ArrayList<Offer>(2000);

public Offers() {
}

public static void saveOffers() {
        for (Offer offer : offers) {
            if (offer == null) {
                continue;
            }
            int id = offer.id;
            int item = offer.item;
            int amount = offer.amount;
            int price = offer.price;
            int currentAmount = offer.currentAmount;
            int removedAmount = offer.removedAmount;
            int type = offer.type;
            int completed = offer.completed ? 1 : 0;
            int aborted = offer.aborted ? 1 : 0;
            int currentPrice = offer.currentPrice;
            int slot = offer.slot;
            String owner = offer.owner;
            String VALUES(""+ id + "" + item + "" + amount + "" + price + "" + currentAmount + "" + removedAmount + "" + type + "" + completed + "" + aborted + "" + currentPrice + "" + slot + "" + owner + "");
        }
    }
}

public static void load() {
    BufferedReader stream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            new FileInputStream("GEoffers.txt")));
            int id = stream.readShort();
            int item = stream.read();
            int amount = stream.read();
            int price = stream.read();
            int currentAmount = stream.read();
            int removedAmount = stream.read();
            int type = stream.readShort();
            boolean completed = stream.readShort() == 1;
            boolean aborted = stream.readShort() == 1;
            int currentPrice = stream.read();
            int slot = stream.readShort();
            String owner = stream.readString();
            if (id != -1)
                offers.add(new Offer(id, item, amount, currentAmount, removedAmount, price, type, owner, completed, slot));
            for (Offer l : offers) {
                if (l == null) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (l.id == id && l.item == item && l.amount == amount && l.currentAmount == currentAmount && l.price == price && l.type == type && l.owner.equals(owner) && l.slot == slot) {
                    l.currentPrice = currentPrice;
                    l.aborted = aborted;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

What I'm trying to do in the same method is save all that into a string so when the load method is called it will load & set the variables to what was saved in that string.
for example saves as `""+ id + "" + item + "" + amount + "" + price + "" + currentAmount + "" + removedAmount + "" + type + "" + completed + "" + aborted + "" + currentPrice + "" + slot + "" + owner + ""` 
and loads as the same while setting the variables as they were when saved.

I'm so done with this I'm on the edge of paying someone like 5$ to just do it for me. Just asking for some help or if someone could be kind enough to fix my crap work. ++*10 for help.

Offer Class as requested:

```
public class Offer {

public int id = -1;
public int item = 0;
public int amount = 0;
public int currentAmount = 0;
public int removedAmount = 0;
public int price = 0;
public int type = 0;
public String owner = "";
public boolean completed = false;
public int currentPrice = 0;
public boolean aborted = false;
public int slot = 0;
public boolean itemsLeft = false;

/**
 * Creates a new global offer.
 * 
 * @param id
 * @param item
 * @param amount
 * @param currentAmount
 * @param removedAmount
 * @param price
 * @param type
 * @param owner
 * @param completed
 * @param slot
 */
public Offer(int id, int item, int amount, int currentAmount, int removedAmount, int price, int type, String owner, boolean completed, int slot) {
    this.id = id;
    this.item = item;
    this.amount = amount;
    this.currentAmount = currentAmount;
    this.removedAmount = removedAmount;
    this.price = price;
    this.type = type;
    this.owner = owner;
    this.completed = completed;
    this.slot = slot;
    this.itemsLeft = false;
}

public void updatePrice(int amount, boolean bool) {
    if (bool) {
        currentPrice += amount;
    } else {
        currentPrice -= amount;
    }
}

public void clear() {
    id = -1;
    item = 0;
    amount = 0;
    currentAmount = 0;
    price = 0;
    type = -1;
    owner = "";
    completed = false;
    currentPrice = 0;
    aborted = false;
    itemsLeft = false;
}

public void delete() {
    Offers.offers.remove(this);
}
```

}

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: This is not a site that will do your homework. Show us what error you are getting.

Comment: You haven't added any `Offer`s to the list

Comment: Please post Offer class also

Comment: posted offer class as requested

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want something like this

```
public class Offers {

    public static List<Offer> offers = new ArrayList<Offer>(2000);

    public Offers() {
    }

    public void saveOffers(int id, int item, int amount, int currentAmount, 
                           int removedAmount, int price, int type, String owner, 
                           boolean completed, int slot) {

        Offer offer = new Offer(id, item, amount, currentAmount, removedAmount, 
                                price, type, owner, completed, slot)

       offers.add(offer);
   }
}
```

You haven't added any `Offer`s to the `offers` list. So you cant change the values. That's why you're getting null. `ArrayList<>(2000)` doesnt add 2000 Offers, just creates a capacity of 2000. Depending on how you define `Offer` class and it's constructors and getter method (if any), you may want something like my code above.

To run it

```
public class TestOffers {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Offers offers = new Offers();

        int id  = 1;
        int item = 1;
        int amount = 1;
        int currentAmount = 1; 
        int removedAmount = 1;
        int price = 10;
        int type =- 1;
        String owner = "Me";
        boolean completed = true;
        int slot =1;

        offers.saveOffers(id, item, amount, currentAmount, removedAmount, 
                                          price, type, owner, completed, slot);

        for (Offer offer : offers){
            System.out.println(offer);
        }
    }
}
```

You'll also want to override the `toString()` method in your `Offer` class, in order to get your desired output when you want to print an `offer`

```
public class Offer {
   ...

   @Override
   public String toString(){
       return id + " " + item + " " + amount + " " + price + " " 
              + currentAmount + " " + removedAmount + " " + type + " " 
              + completed + " " + aborted + " " + currentPrice + " " 
              + slot + " " + owner;
   }
}
```

Comment: I need to save it to a file. When I try to save it to player files (player) it doesn't show to the world. I need to to be saved to a file. But yes this is along the line & very close to what i'm trying to accomplish. But I don't need test offer's. those variables are set from a different class.

Comment: And where is your method to write the to the file?

Comment: And where is your `main` method where you're running the program from? You may need to explain to me step by step what you're trying to accomplish, becuase I have no idea just by looking at code. I can only which, which is what I've been doing because you're explanations aren't that good.

Comment: I'm literally just trying to save the ints & the string(owner) into a single string & can do something like this inside the file:
100, 50, 10, 500000, 200, 0, 1, 1, 0, 500000, 1, me
100, 50, 10, 500000, 200, 0, 1, 1, 0, 500000, 2, me2

Comment: And where would you like to save this string, and where is the method you attempted to save to the file?

Comment: C:\ drive no sub folders. just right there in the c drive. Anything else you need to know?

Comment: What METHOD are you using? Where is your attemped method at performing this save task? I dont need to know where it's being saved. I can't just make up a method for you. I can help you fix one you have that doesn't work.

Comment: I did not mean where in your file system you want to save the string, but where in your program are you saving this String to put into the file system.

Comment: And where does the information come that makes up this string. I need all this info and the above info. Please explain it to me in terms of what code of your i need to look at to see what your talking about. I can't just search your code and guess what you're talking about.

Comment: Why do you need to know all that info. you literally just need to know the save method which is in the first class I posted very top. My save & load methods are right there. all I need is for it to save when the save method is called & the load method to load when called. I'll deal with setting the ints & string.

Comment: You have a BufferedReader. You want a Writer

Comment: I have a buffered reader in my load method. so do I write a buffered write for the save method? & how would I save all that to a string? & have it repeat in the file like my example above?

Comment: That's why I asked all the questions above. I did not understand that the infor was coming from the load, And I did not know the saveOffer method was the one to save to file.  Next time someone asks you a question, answer it, don't get an attitude. They're asking the question because they don't understand what you're trying to do. And yes, you need a writer in your save method.